# Website error when I backed up my website from my old web host and restored the site onto my new web host

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-2.5, joomla-3.4, joomla-3.3.x

I just recently backed up my Joomla website from my old web host and transferred the domain to my new web host. I then restored the database files and SQL files as well as corrected the configuration.php file to the new database. When the transfer had completed I pointed the domain to the correct folder including the database files. When I go to the domain, a page pops up with the following info below. I'm not sure what happened, I typically transfer and restore WordPress websites all the time and this is my first time transferring a Joomla site.

Any help is appreciated thanks everyone:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package    Joomla.Site
 *
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2016 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

/**
 * Define the application's minimum supported PHP version as a constant so it can be referenced within the application.
 */
define('JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP', '5.3.10');

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP, '<'))
{
    die('Your host needs to use PHP ' . JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP . ' or higher to run this version of Joomla!');
}

// Saves the start time and memory usage.
$startTime = microtime(1);
$startMem  = memory_get_usage();

/**
 * Constant that is checked in included files to prevent direct access.
 * define() is used in the installation folder rather than "const" to not error for PHP 5.2 and lower 
 */
define('_JEXEC', 1);

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))
{
    include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Set profiler start time and memory usage and mark afterLoad in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->setStart($startTime, $startMem)->mark('afterLoad') : null;

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Execute the application.
$app->execute();
```

Comment: Can you let us know what version of Joomla the site is running and have you verified that your host is indeed running PHP 5.3.

Comment: Thank you for your response Farahmand, I am very new to Joomla and someone had developed this site that i no longer have contact with. Is it possible to find the Joomla version through the primary files on the FTP? Regarding your second question, we have verified it is running PHP 5.6

Comment: Is there a README.txt file in your root? It would be at the top. "This is a Joomla! installation/upgrade package to version 3.x" Another thing to verify is that php is setup and running on your website. You could do that with a phpinfo page. http://v1.jontangerine.com/silo/php/phpinfo/

Comment: Thanks NJA, yes there is a README.txt that says - This is a Joomla! installation/upgrade package to version 3.x and more information below. I will verify that php is running on the site an get back you. Thank NJA -

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you first make sure the new hosting service can support Joomla. Download a fresh copy of Joomla which is currently version 3.6.0, and install it with the sample data. If you get that working, then you know it is something that was over looked in the configuration in the transfer.

Comment: Thank you Edward_178118 will do. I will let you know my results.